# Binning Pandas Series and passing user defined label

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am working in Python. I would like to have the bins of income. If income is missing then null, if 0< income >=25000 then bucket '0-25k', if 25000< income >=50000 then bucket '25k-50k' and so on till the income is greater than 500k. I tried using the cut functionality in Pandas but could not get desired output.

Comment: please read this; [ask], [mcve]